# Safari update for MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, safari

Trying to update Safari 11.1.2 and I keep getting an error message.  Something about unable to update because of an extension in use in Spotlight.

I can quit the application - but Spotlight is not an application.

Comment: what  extension ?

Comment: Try searching for `Spotlight` or `Safari` in your Activity Monitor and see if something pops up.

Answer (score 1):

Don’t install/remove anything, instead, quit Spotlight from Activity Monitor once that message pops up and it will continue. Spotlight automatically restarts.